# Top 2 values from array using inject

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to get the top 2 values from this array using `inject`,

```
a = [1, 2, 5, 7, 4, 9, 2]

b = a.inject(Array.new(2) {0}) {|r, e|
  if e > r[0]
    r[1] = r[0]
    r[0] = e
  end
}
```

but I keep getting the error `'block in <main>': undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` at the line `r[1] = r[0]`

How could I change it so that `r[0]` would represent the largest value from `a`, and `r[1]` the second largest? Or is there a better, more ruby-like way altogether?

Comment: By "top 2", do you mean "the two largest" or "the two most frequent"? I'm guessing "the two largest" so you want `[9, 7]`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't make that more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
a.sort[-2, 2]
=> [7, 9]
```

If you require the reverse order (and using `last(2)` from @mu):

```
a.sort.last(2).reverse
=> [9, 7]
```

As far as `inject` goes it always requires that the so called memo object is returned from the block, so that it will be available in the next loop iteration. So this would fix your code:

```
b = a.inject([0, 0]) { |r, e|
  # Added fix from @Chuck
  if e > r[0] 
    r[0], r[1] = e, r[0] 
  elsif e > r[1] 
    r[1] = e 
  end
  r # <- add this line
}
```

Comment: Your inject version isn't quite correct. You also need a branch to replace the second value if the current value is the second-biggest found thus far. Basically `if e > r[0] then r[0], r[1] = e, r[0] elsif  e > r[1] then r[1] = e end`